# Use withCredential with $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I want to use resource with a cookie set in the navigator.

With $http it is really easy, as I only need to set withCredential to true:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: user,
    withCredentials: true
});
```

But for $resource, I didn't find a solution to dot the same... I saw a [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1095) on github about that but I think that settings withCredential to true for all requests is not okay. Do you have an idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The config `withCredentials` in [$resource](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.2/docs/api/ngResource.%24resource) module is available in AngularJS 1.1.2+, you can get the new version and give it a try.

Answer (score 19):

To change the default settings of [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (hence `$resource`), you need to alter [`$httpProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider).

Set `withCredentials` globally like that:

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP')
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set it the flag globally with:

```
 $http.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

This will affect all requests from the `$resource` module as well as the `$http` module.